# How to embed native android apis' in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm a programming newbie , started coding may 2017.

I want to access location and storage of user's mobile in both Android and iPhone using flutter . Is there any way I can embed native Code in flutter?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Asking question format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: You should split each question you have up into a separate question here. The Flutter documentation has an extensive section on integrating with native or platform specific code: https://flutter.io/platform-plugins/ Storing values locally can be achieved using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences, for a list of available plugins check https://flutter.io/platform-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

You can **write platform specific code** in Flutter, [refer this doc](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)

You can check [this article](https://medium.com/nonstopio/embedding-flutter-in-existing-android-project-733dccacde12) about **embedding flutter in native app.**

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter documentation on [platform plugins](https://flutter.io/platform-plugins/) explains how to interoperate with native APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [this Flutter package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location) for location access and there is a guide on Flutter's site about [File I/O](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/).